# What happens when I run python -v on the terminal instead of python -V?

Tags: python-3.x, bash, ubuntu

A huge list sprung up on my terminal after I misstyped python -v into my terminal. listing a few here:

```
     # clear builtins._
     # clear sys.path
     # clear sys.argv
     # clear sys.ps1
     # clear sys.ps2
     # clear sys.last_type
```

I have no idea what is happening.

Comment: I added a small tutorial on using the man pages- knowing how to use them will make your searches for information SOOO much easier :D

Comment: Thank you @Ben. I will go through them as I wrap my head around bash scripting

Answer (score 3):

when you type `python` on terminal or command prompt then it will open python interpreter in interactive mode.

```
$ python
Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan 16 2018, 12:04:33)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

When you type `python -v` , then it will open do the same thing but in verbose mode so you will see lots of messages which tell that which module is being initialized and from where. You will also see messages regardign module clean up when you type `exit()`

You can type -vv to make it more verbose

If you want to see the version of python then use `python --version` or `python -V` (Please note capital V)

More details can be found here:

https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-v

> -v Print a message each time a module is initialized, showing the place (filename or built-in module) from which it is loaded. When
>   given twice (-vv), print a message for each file that is checked for
>   when searching for a module. Also provides information on module
>   cleanup at exit. See also PYTHONVERBOSE.

Comment: Thank you @Nikhil, your explanation was very helpful. I was actually trying to figure out my version of python when I mistyped.

Answer (score 1):

From `man python`:

```
      -v      Print a message each time a module is initialized,  showing  the
              place  (filename  or  built-in  module) from which it is loaded.
              When given twice, print a message for each file that is  checked
              for  when  searching for a module.  Also provides information on
              module cleanup at exit.
```

As a side note, the next time you want to know what a particular command switch does, use the following commands:

```
man <command>
```

This places you in the `man` pages. You can move up and down with `j` and `k`, exit with `q`. To search, type `/search_term` and jump between matches with `n` and `N`.

So, in this case:

```
man python
```

Now we're in the man pages for Python. Search for the switch in question:

```
/-v
```

Use `n` to jump to the next match and `N` if you overshoot it until you find the relevant passage.

Comment: Also worth noting, it enters the interactive python shell, so you can quit out of python normally with like quit()